# My Question is is it haram to take picture of a food before eating?

Tags: hadith, dua, food, image

As i have seen many people mostly our muslim, instead of reciting holy verses (بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم). They are taking their meal pictures and posting it on their Instagram for to get likes and fame. 
I have tried my best to stop many with such activity so can you help me with the same. 
Does islamic hadiths related to this.

Jazak Allah.

Comment: Why do you think it would be haram? And are you seriously asking if there is a hadith about photographs and instagram?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, taking pictures from what you have is not HARAM but If you are completely sure that these pictures harm someone, it's better not to do it but finally, it's not haram.

Answer (score 0):

Showing off is not good. If you take the pictures and keep them to yourself , then you won't have a problem. If you post it to millions of people then some people might get jealous and eventually you will be harmed.

Comment: I think your making this seem a lot more serious than it actually is. I understand if this person posts pictures to a website for starving people and mocks the poor etc but this is just a simple picture. If anything bad was to come out of it I think they should remove it then but taking a picture of food isnt anything to cause a ruckus about.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the perspective and intention *(niat)* of taking those pictures, it can be either **halal** or **haram**.

If those pictures taken and publicized to the public can lead to fitnah or other sort of evil thoughts, then surely it would be considered as haram on doing so.

On the other hand, if those pictures taken is just for personal used or to be used as a discussion instead for example, then it is totally fine. Myself too has sometimes take pictures of the food that I'm eating, just to inform my mother that I am eating well and not wanting her to worry when I am far away from home.